# AWS Account Bandwidth ussage getting high

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, cloud, terraform

I have creating t2.micro instance using following security group in terraform.

**Allow 80 Port**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "access-http" {
  name          = "Allow-80"
  description   = "Allow 80 inbound traffic"
   ingress {
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

**Allow 8080 Port**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "access-http-web" {
  name          = ""
  description   = "Allow 8080 inbound traffic"  
  ingress {
    from_port = 8080
    to_port = 8080
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

**Allow 22 Port**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "access-ssh" {
  name = "Access-ssh"
  ingress {
    from_port = 22
    to_port   = 22
    protocol  = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port = 1194
    to_port   = 1194
    protocol  = "udp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }   

}
```

If any security issue came in due this security group. I have used Network(VPC) and Subnet option is default selected one. Please advise me.

Comment: The question is not clear, are you getting any bandwidth related issues? 

From your security groups, seems to me you have allowed the world to SSH into your instance [0.0.0.0/0], which is never a good thing to do. Restrict the SSH access to specific locations only.

I would suggest you to go through this whitepaper if you are trying to secure your AWS environment - https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/aws-security-best-practices/

Comment: I am new to Cloud. Some one access my instance. Due to this my bandwidth usage getting high. So I need to restrict.

Comment: Exactly. You have "allowed" anyone to access your instance. Restrict the inbound SSH access to specific IPs. Do not keep 0.0.0.0/0 in the IP address range for port 22 (SSH).  Some reference rules listed here -
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules-reference.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was me I would terminate the instance and create a new one. When you create the "Allow 22 Port" security group you should make sure the source address is your current IP address. If your public (home/office) IP address is dynamic then you will need to check each time you connect and update it in the Security Group via the console if it has changed.